# Suppose the sides of a triangle form a geometric progression with common ratio r. Then what interval does r lie in? ( Options are down below)

Tags: geometry, geometric-progressions

Options are

**A** ***(*** 0,  (-1+✓5)/2 **]**

**B** ***(*** (1+✓5)/2 , (2+✓5)2 **]**

**C**  ***(*** (-1+✓5)/2 , (1+✓5)/2 **]**

**D**  ***(*** (2+✓5)/2 , Infinity **)**

Im just a 12 th grade  . So i request answer with explanation please.

Comment: Hint: Use the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The longest side can't be longer than the sum of the other two sides.

$a + ar > ar^2$

$a(1 + r) > ar^2$

$1 + r > r^2$

$r^2 - r - 1 < 0$

$r < \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} = 1.618$ for an increasing progression

$r > \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2} = \frac{1}{1.618} = .618$ for a decreasing progression